# Binomial Probability with Unknown p

Tags: probability

I need help with understanding this question:

When you repeatedly play a game with chance of success being $p$, $0 < p < 1$, then the chance of winning at least once in $\lceil{\frac{7}{10p}}\rceil$ trials is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$. Show that is true for all small $p > 0$.

Whatever I use (I've tried with $X \sim B(\lceil{\frac{7}{10p}}\rceil, p)$ and then with a Poisson approximation) I get a function of $p$ that is either true for all $p$ in the given range or none of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that the probability of losing every time is less than $1/2$. The probability of losing every time is 
$$(1-p)^{\lceil 7/(10p)\rceil}.$$
The logarithm of this is $\lceil 7/(10p)\rceil\log(1-p)$, which is less than $-p\lceil 7/(10p)\rceil$, which in turn is less than $-7/10$. And $e^{-7/10}$ is a little less than $0.5$.